# Iterator class with specified length of steps

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write iterator class that will allow me to specify the length of steps the iterator makes. But I am stuck with that problem.

My code:

```
class Reverse:
    def __init__(self, data, step):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)
        self.step = step
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self, step):
        if self.index <= 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - self.step
        return self.data[self.index]

rev = Reverse('Drapsicle', 2)
```

this shows me letter 'l' always

```
rev.__next__(2)
```

but loop gives me: =TypeError: **next**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'step'`:

```
for char in rev:
    print(char)
```

Comment: You seem to be requiring a `step` argument in `__next__` but not using it, just using `self.step`.

Comment: do you want to emulate: `'Drapsicle'[::-2]`?

Comment: no, not really, thanks anyway

Comment: What is the desired output? Do you want: `''.join(Reverse('Drapsicle', 2))  == 'ecsaD'` or something else? What is the expected input? Is it always a string? Could it be a type with just `__reversed__` method ([see `reversed()` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `__next__` method should not take any arguments (other than `self`). You are not even using the `step` argument, you are (correctly) using `self.step`. Just remove the argument:

```
def __next__(self):
    if self.index <= 0:
        raise StopIteration
    self.index = self.index - self.step
    return self.data[self.index]
```

Next, you have an error; you want to test if the index drops below `0` *after* subtracting, otherwise you generate negative indices. You could test the index together with the step subtracted:

```
def __next__(self):
    next_index = self.index - self.step
    if next_index < 0:
        raise StopIteration
    self.index = next_index
    return self.data[self.index]
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Reverse:
...     def __init__(self, data, step):
...         self.data = data
...         self.index = len(data)
...         self.step = step
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return self
...     def __next__(self):
...         next_index = self.index - self.step
...         if next_index < 0:
...             raise StopIteration
...         self.index = next_index
...         return self.data[self.index]
... 

>>> rev = Reverse('Drapsicle', 2)
>>> for char in rev:
...     print(char)
... 
l
i
p
r
```

Comment: This returns `'e'` before it runs out; `self.index = self.index - self.step` should be above the `if`.

Comment: @Cyphase: well spotted; adjusted answer to compensate.

Comment: OP probably wants an [analog of `'Drapsicle'[::-2]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32138809/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: that works for lists, but Cyphase's answer at least works for anything supporting `__reversed__` iteration.

Comment: Notice  *"an analog of"* in the comment. **Obviously**, if you have a list then you could use the extended slicing directly and you don't need the custom class. The point of the example is to suggest the possible result (which items should be in the result).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not a direct answer to the question, but in case you just want to get the job done, and think you need to implement it all yourself; you don't.

```
from itertools import islice

def reverse_step(iterable, step):
    # To behave like your code; starts with step-th item
    start = step - 1

    for item in islice(reversed(iterable), start, None, step)):
        yield item
```

Comment: I think OP wants: `islice(reversed('Drapsicle'), None, None, 2)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I don't think so. The question indicates `'l'` was the first value OP was receiving, without any mention of that being wrong, and OP replied positively to Martijn's answer that returned `l, i, p, r`.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this:

```
>>> 'Drapsicle'[::-2]
'ecsaD'
```

as your own iterator:

```
class Reverse:
    def __init__(self, data, step):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data) - 1
        self.step = step
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.index < 0:
            raise StopIteration
        value = self.data[self.index] 
        self.index -= self.step
        return value
```

Example:

```
>>> list(Reverse('Drapsicle', 2))
['e', 'c', 's', 'a', 'D']
```

Note:

- `self.index` starts with `len - 1`
- `__next__()` does not accept any argument except `self`
- first you get `value` then you decrement the index

A more flexible design would separate the reversing (e.g., delegate it to the `reversed()` builtin) and using `step != 1` (accept an arbitrary reversible iterable and/or use/implement extended slicing) e.g., based on [@Cyphase's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32138404/4279):

```
>>> list(islice(reversed('Drapsicle'), None, None, 2))
['e', 'c', 's', 'a', 'D']
```